# Why is the hot water pipe from this small boiler norprene, not metal? And could it be replaced with a metal pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, boiler, hot-water

The diagram[image] (full pdf instructions [here](http://www.eastmidlandswater.com/prod_images/install_lbutler_1000.pdf)) is of a small boiler that fits under a kitchen sink, and keeps a small amount of water constantly near boiling which you can use for cups of tea etc. (its my parents - I know, fancy!) It has a valve in the tap which allows the pressure to escape when not in use.

The problem is the hot water outlet pipe is made of flexible norprene hose (unlike the cold water inlets which are copper), which degrades quickly with use, and constantly has to be replaced which is expensive and annoying.

Why have they used norprene here rather than metal pipe? Could this be replaced with a metal pipe?

Many thanks!

Comment: "Norprene Tubing. The Norprene Family of Tubing Products is formulated for flexural resistance and high temperatures. Norpene does not easily crack or deteriorate even in physically demanding application."    This stuff is normally industrial food service use item and should last.  Does it appear to be deteriorating from inside or outside?

Comment: It seems to be very furred up on the inside - I suppose some kind of deposit from the boiling mains water. Its actually only failed twice in the last year or so, but each time they have to get a plumber out to fix it as its tricky since you have to disconnect the entire thing to get to the hot water connections and risky also as its connected directly to the mains. Last time there was a split a couple of cms long in it apparently - I dont know how to tell if it from inside or outside, but I guess inside due to the furring?

Comment: I wonder if the furry stuff is either clogging the line leading to an over pressure or some how eating at the material.  Do they have a  softener that could be leaving salts in the line?  Is there a house filter that filters out minerals.